# Make IrfanView ignore text files or other file types?

Tags: file-types, textfiles, irfanview

I just installed [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.net) and while viewing images, I notice IrfanView iterates text files as well as image files. How do I make it NOT include text files (or other kinds of files) in its iteration?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

In Irfanview, go to **Options menu | Properties/Settings | Extentions**. Now,

### Option 1

- Check the boxes for the file extensions you want to associate with Irfanview
- Select the option "Load only associated types while moving through directory".
- Restart IrfanView

### Option 2

- Select the option "Load custom file types".
- Carefully copy and paste the long text string into Notepad or another text editor; now you can more easily examine and edit the chosen filetypes.
- Remove the `TXT|` substring.
- Copy and paste the long text string back into the textbox in the Properties dialog.
- Restart IrfanView

Comment: FYI, make sure to hit the Ok button in the middle left of the Settings dialog, otherwise the updated settings are silently discarded.

Comment: You need to restart irfanview too.